# Vue.js: Data is not updating on change

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, pusher

I have a Laravel, Vue.js2 and Pusher stack. In the created() I'm able to subscribe to pusher channel and listen to it. I can even log the event data in the console, however, I'm not able to set it in the data value on FE. Does anybody know why?

```
    <template>
  <div class="flex flex-col items-center b p-10 rounded shadow-lg bg-white">
    
    <p class="text-xl text-blueGray-800 leading-relaxed mt-6">Aktuálna cena:</p>
    <div class="flex flex-col items-center justify-evenly w-full mt-3 mb-6">
      <div>
        <h1 class="text-xl md:text-4xl mb-4 font-bold font-heading">
          {{ price.value }} €
        </h1>
      </div>
      <div>
        <a
          href="#"
          class="bg-black"
          @click="raisePrice"
          >Add 100 €</a
        >
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr class="w-full mb-6" />
    
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ["id", "bidder_id"],
  data() {
    return {
      auction: null,
      price: '',
      newPrice: null,
    };
  },

  created() {
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common = {
      "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
      "X-CSRF-TOKEN": document
        .querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]')
        .getAttribute("content"),
    };
    this.fetchPrice();
    

    Pusher.logToConsole = true;

    var pusher = new Pusher("123456789", {
      cluster: "eu",
    });

    var channel = pusher.subscribe(this.id.toString());

    channel.bind("price-raise", function (data) {
      this.price.value = data.price;
    });
  },

  methods: {
    fetchPrice() {
      axios.get(`/auction/${this.id}`).then((response) => {
        this.auction = response.data;
        this.price = {"value": response.data.actual_price};
        
      });
    },

    raisePrice() {
      this.newPrice = this.price.value + 100;
      this.price.value = this.price.value + 100;
      const req_data = {
        actual_price: this.newPrice,
        id: this.id,
        bidder_id: parseInt(this.bidder_id),
      };
      axios
        .post("/auction/raise/" + this.id, req_data)
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Does anybody know how it suppose to be to update/re-render the {{price.value}} once pusher shoots a message??

PS: on raisePrice() method it changes (everytime button is clicked)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thinks this is issue with context (`this` keyword).

```js
channel.bind("price-raise", function (data) {
      // 'this' reference here is not the reference to vue-component
      this.price.value = data.price;
});
```

You should either use arrow-function...

```js
channel.bind("price-raise",  (data) =>  this.price.value = data.price);
```

...or an old-school `that` lifehack:

```js
var that = this;
channel.bind("price-raise", function (data) {
      that.price.value = data.price;
    });
```

Comment: No, I'm subscribed all the time and recieving events and it writes into this.price.value, because if I console.log it it shows up.. However, doesn't change on  FE

Comment: Edited my answer, maybe this can help

Comment: Amazing! it works now, thank you. (used the arrow-function)